# How can I use Javascript to manipulate text inside '<div contenteditable' from a website?

Tags: javascript, applescript, contenteditable, getelementsbyclassname

Please help, how can I change (or get) the text "19000" in the image using javascript? I need to know it to automate tasks filling in some blanks logging in website and more. Thank you.[image: https://shopee.vn/buyer/login This is a site I want to crawl the informations.]

https://shopee.vn/buyer/login This is  a site I want to crawl the informations.

Comment: Do you have access of this site source or are you crawling informations in it? This input has a MVVM backend (or similar). You will be able to access it via [Shadow Root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/shadowRoot) of the element or thorugh the backend API

Comment: https://shopee.vn/buyer/login This is just a site I want to crawl the informations. Thx you!

Comment: I will not reply specifically to this because it is a login form and can be used for bad intentions, generally speacking you usually use `document.querySelector` and [`Shadow Root`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/shadowRoot) to access the elements in the dom through css classes and ids (dom selectors).

Answer (score 0):

If you give the div tag an id attribute such as

```
<div id="my_id">Some Text</div>
```

then you can can change the text it contains from JavaScript using

```
document.getElementById("my_id").innerHTML = "New text";
```

Comment: Yeah, nice, but how can I give the div tag an id attribute? I don't know how. https://shopee.vn/buyer/login This is  a site I want to crawl the informations.

Comment: You can't access directly from dom an element inside a shadow root

Answer (score 0):

if you can set an id of that element then use `document.getElementById("<your id>")` or if you only know the attribute of that element and cannot add id, loop through all elements in document and compare attributes to find that you are searching for like this:

```
function search(node ,name, value) {
    if(node.getAttribute && node.getAttribute(name) == value) {
        node.getAttribute && console.log(node.getAttribute("hello"))
        return node
    }

    for(var i in node.childNodes) {
        const res = search(node.childNodes[i], name, value)
        if(res) return res
    }
}
console.log(search(document.getElementsByTagName("HTML")[0], "contenteditable", "plaintext-only"))
```

this will find one of possible elements (excuse my grammar)

then when you have an element in a variable you can use `element.innerHTML = "text"`